# Proving that there are infinitely many primes $p$ that $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ .

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

$x^2-2$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ ($x=\bar{0}$
 is a root for $x^2-2$). Similarly for $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ ($x^2-2=x^2+2=x^2+3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$. However $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.
Proving that there are infinitely many $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ in which $x^2-2$ is irreducible.

Comment: You've made a mistake in your calculation: $x^2 - 2\not\equiv x^2 + 2\pmod{3},$ because $2\not\equiv -2\pmod{3}.$ You can plug $1$ or $2$ into $x^2 - 2$ to see that you do not get $0$ modulo $3.$ When $x = 1,$ you get $1 - 2\equiv -1\equiv 2\not\equiv 0\pmod{3},$ and when $x = 2,$ you get $4 - 2\equiv 1\not\equiv 0\pmod{3}.$

Answer (score 2):

Well, note that you have $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=-1$ for primes of the from $\pm{3}\pmod{8}$. And there are infinitely many primes of the form $8n\pm 3$, like $3,5,11,\cdots$

Here $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ denotes the Legendre's Symbol.

Comment: Why for this kinds of primes, $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$? (for $\mathbb{Z}_3$ it is not!)

Comment: @smakh Because $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = -1$ precisely when $x^2 - a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has no solution. As $x^2 - a$ is a quadratic polynomial, it is irreducible [modulo $p$] if and only if there is no solution to $x^2 - a\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$ See my comment under your question regarding $p=3.$ You should look up "quadratic reciprocity" if you do not already know this theorem.

Comment: would you please introduce me a text for study?

Comment: I like *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Hardy and Wright

Comment: @smakh Introduction to Theory of Numbers by I. Niven, H. Montgomery or Introduction to Analytic Number theory by Tom Apostol.  Both are amazing text books for reading about these things.